# UIImagePickerController shows album listing rows with gray background

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery, xcode9.1

I have implemented functionality to select image from Galley. When I am presenting UIImagePickerController, Its shows album listing with grey background. I tried with demo app but it shows proper white background.No getting why its showing Grey in my app as code is same in both.Please refer attached image.[image]

Comment: May be your ViewController have black background color

Comment: have you done any appearance settings in appDelegate?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for hint. I had UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor in appdelegate